# Increment the patch in a version number

Tags: yq

I have a YAML file with [semantic versioning number](https://semver.org/) like this:

```yaml
version: 1.0.1
```

I need to increment PATCH part of the version. Is it possible to do it with yq?

UPDATE:
The question is about [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) implementation which is installed with `brew install yq`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please clarify [which implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) of `yq` you are using. Apart from that, the general approach would be to split the string at the dots, convert the last item to a number and increment it, and then rejoin the array with dots.

Here's one way of doing it using the [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) implementation:

```bash
.version |= (./"." | last |= tonumber + 1 | join("."))
```

And here's the same using the [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) implementation:

```bash
.version |= (split(".") | .[-1] |= ((. tag = "!!int") + 1) | join("."))
```

Comment: I didn't find a way how to cast a string to an integer. Thank you.